# Uncertainty principle manifesting in $j(j+1)$ vs $j^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, lie-algebra

To motivate my question, please consider a system with total angular momentum $j$. The fact that the largest eigenvalue of $J_z$ is $j$, while $J^2 = J_x^2 + J_y^2 + J_z^2$ has all eigenvalues equal to $j(j+1)$ is often ascribed to the uncertainty principle.

For example, quoting page $51$ of the textbook "Models of Quantum Matter" by Hans-Peter Eckle,

> "...However, the eigenvalue of $L^2$ is $l(l+1)$, larger than $l^2$.
> This implies that the angular momentum operator $\bf{L}$ can never
> align with certainty with $L_3$ and the uncertainty principle is
> satisfied. If $\bf{L}$ could be aligned with $L_3$, then $L_1=L_2=0$
> and we would have simultaneously sharp values of all three components
> of the angular momentum operator, in contradiction to Heisenberg's
> uncertainty relations..."

---

To what extent is this reasoning true in general? It is hard for me to formulate my question more precisely, but I will attempt to do so:

Consider some set of Hermitian operators $K_i$ which all pairwise do not commute but instead each commute with the sum of their squares, $K^2 = \sum_i K_i^2$. Is it guaranteed that $K^2$'s largest eigenvalue is **strictly** greater than any of the eigenvalues of the individual $K_i^2$? The strictly greater is key, as it is greater than or equal by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1622770). I hope to see that the failure of the individual $K_i$ to commute amongst themselves imposes a stronger statement.

Comment: I think you also need to assume that $K^2$ commutes with all the $K_i$ in order to have a potential problem with the uncertainty principle (otherwise $K^2$ itself is not observable at the same time as the $K_i$). I think that could potentially be an important point, since $K^2$ being an invariant (ie, commuting with each $K_i$) points to having a rotational symmetry.

Comment: @Andrew That's a good point about needing $K^2$ to be commuting with the $K_i$ in order to bump up against the uncertainty principle. I've edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following two operators $A$ and $B$ have the properties that:

- $A$ and $B$ do not commute;
- $A^2 + B^2$ commutes with both $A$ and $B$; and
- the largest eigenvalue of $A^2$ equals the largest eigenvalue of $A^2 + B^2$:

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix} \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & i/\sqrt{2} \\ 0 & -i/\sqrt{2} & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
for $\lambda \geq 1$. We have
$$
[A, B] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -i & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & i \end{bmatrix} \neq 0
$$
so the two operators do not commute.  However,
$$
A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 
\lambda^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad
 A^2 + B^2 = \begin{bmatrix} 
\lambda^2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
and we can see that for any $\lambda > 1$, the largest eigenvalues of both $A^2$ and $A^2 + B^2$ are $\lambda^2$.  It can also be easily shown that $A^2 + B^2$ commutes with both $A$ and $B$.

The "loophole" being exploited here is that $[A, B]$ has a non-trivial null space even though the commutator does not itself vanish.  Since $A$ and $B$ are simultaneously diagonalizable on this subspace, we're allowed to have a state with zero uncertainty of $A$ and $B$ lying within this subspace.

Comment: This is very nice. Is the converse true that if $[A,B]$ has a trivial null space then one must get strictly greater than?

Comment: @user196574:  That would be the obvious question, but I don't immediately see a way to prove it.  I'll have to think on it further.